# How to read Ethereum contract storage values which are not emitted?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, web3py

I want to read the contract storage for `'0x9EC55d57208cb28a7714A2eA3468bD9d5bB15125'` at block `16368474` on BSC .
I tried -

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const rpcURL = "https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org/"
const web3 = new Web3(rpcURL)

let contractAddress = '0x9EC55d57208cb28a7714A2eA3468bD9d5bB15125'
for (index = 0; index < 10; index++){
 console.log(`[${index}]` + 
   web3.eth.getStorageAt(contractAddress, index,16368474).then(res=>{ 
    console.log(res)
   }) 
   )
}
```

This runs into an error `Error: Returned error: header not found` .I tried changing blocks but run into the same error . The error only resolves if I don't pass `16368474` but that uses the `latest` block and that's not what I want . I tried the same with `web3.py` . It runs into the same error. What am I doing wrong ? Is there an alternate way of getting storage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is valid - the issue is that the node provider doesn't support querying historic states.

Solution: Use a different provider that supports archive node, e.g. [Moralis](https://docs.moralis.io/speedy-nodes/connecting-to-rpc-nodes/connect-to-bsc-node).

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3("https://speedy-nodes-nyc.moralis.io/<your_api_key>/bsc/mainnet/archive");
const contractAddress = '0x9EC55d57208cb28a7714A2eA3468bD9d5bB15125';
web3.eth.getStorageAt(contractAddress, 0, 16368474).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```